# Auto-update backend data with Aurelia fetch?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Sorry if this is a basic question, I can't seem to find what I need in the Aurelia docs.
So: I have a simple app which basically draws a table using repeats based on json from a backend api I retrieve using the fetch client. Is there a (built-in) way for me to have fetch refresh that data at a set interval?

Comment: You could use a `setInterval` function. Or is there a reason you don't wanna do that?

Comment: great! Nope, that's absolutely an option now that I know about it :-). Still feels like Aurelia is _very_ sparsely documented.